# SharePoint SPD Workflows Multi?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is it okay to have mulltiple workflows doing different things kick off on one activity like (when record changed), if so how do you know which kicks off first?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely ok to have multiple workflows kicking off on the item and also there is no OOB setting for us to set the execution order for these workflows. Are your workflows dependent on other workflows to complete?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to have mulltiple workflows doing different things kick off on one activity like (when record changed),

Yes

> if so how do you know which kicks off first?

You control the order or set a priority on individual workflows. Several options to control the order:

- Create a 2013 workflow that calls 2010 workflows in order.
- Create a group of workflows that fire on item change. Add a column that contains a "step number". Each workflow checks that column to see if it is their turn, if not they just exit. If it is their turn, they do their work, and then change the "step number" to the next step, which triggers the other workflows.
- Create 2013 workflows that loop. They check a column, such as a "step number" column, and then either do their work and exit, or delay for a while and then loop again.
- Create a single master workflow that just has a step for each action to be performed.